# 'Operation is not supported on this platform' when converting ECDH public key to byte array

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, cryptography, ecdh

I have a client application which can be used from both windows and mac os. The application is using ECDH P-384 for key generation. I have below lines of code:

```
var client = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384);
var _publicKey = client.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
```

I am getting

> "Operation is not supported on this platform"

in `client.PublicKey.ToByteArray();` at runtime on macos. This works fine on windows os. The target framework is netcore 3.1 . Also the client is a powershell module and I tried this on powershell 7.1 and powershell 7.2. Am I missing anything for macos in my implementation?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6276

Comment: _This fixed the issue_ - did you have to use `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`?

Comment: Yes I replaced client.PublicKey.ToByteArray(); to client. ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();